# cannot find circular reference reported by autofixture

Tags: tdd, circular-reference, autofixture

I'm trying to validate my infrastructure.  AutoFixture says I have a circular reference in my code and when I omit the behavior, it cannot cast the specimen to my object type.

Charting the solution dependencies yeilds no circular references.  The ouput from autofixture appears to be giving me a path in which a domain object points to a domain object.  I don't understand that... they are pretty plain.

I would just move on since I have a test that passes, but I'd really like to make sure I don't have an unwanted circular reference.  I'm also concerned I won't be able to use AutoFixture later on for isolated components if it isn't building my simple domain object in this example.

Here is the test that succeeds:

```
[Fact]
[UseDataService(typeof(DatabaseVersionService))]
public void DataServiceGetsDatabaseVersionNonAutoFixture()
{
    var sut = new VersionClientProxy(new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DataServiceHostAddress"]));

    var expected = new DatabaseVersion()
    {
        MajorVersionId = 0,
        MinorVersionId = 0,
        BuildVersionId = 0,
        VersionId = 1
    };
     var actual = (from a in sut.DatabaseVersions
                  orderby a.VersionId descending
                  select a).FirstOrDefault();

    Assert.Equal(expected.MajorVersionId, actual.MajorVersionId);
    Assert.Equal(expected.MinorVersionId, actual.MinorVersionId);
    Assert.Equal(expected.BuildVersionId, actual.BuildVersionId);
    Assert.Equal(expected.VersionId, actual.VersionId);
}
```

Here is the test that fails:

```
[Fact]
[UseDataService(typeof(DatabaseVersionService))]
public void DataServiceGetsDatabaseVersion()
{
    var fixture = new Fixture();

    var sut = fixture.Build<VersionClientProxy>().FromFactory<VersionClientProxy>((x) =>
    {
        return new VersionClientProxy(new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DataServiceHostAddress"]));
    }).CreateAnonymous();

    var version = fixture.Build<DatabaseVersion>().FromFactory<DatabaseVersion>((x) =>
    {
        return new DatabaseVersion { MajorVersionId = 0, MinorVersionId = 0, BuildVersionId = 0, VersionId = 1 };
    }).CreateAnonymous();
    var expected = version.AsSource().OfLikeness<DatabaseVersion>();

    var actual = (from a in sut.DatabaseVersions
                  orderby a.VersionId descending
                  select a).FirstOrDefault();
    Assert.True(expected.Equals(actual));
}
```

Here is the client proxy (separate project references only data model project):

```
public class VersionClientProxy : DataServiceContext
{
    public VersionClientProxy(Uri serviceRoot)
        : base(serviceRoot, DataServiceProtocolVersion.V3)
    {
    }

    public IQueryable<DatabaseVersion> DatabaseVersions
    {
        get { return CreateQuery<DatabaseVersion>("DatabaseVersions"); }
    }
}
```

Here is the data service I spin up (service is in separate project references only data model project)

```
public class UseDataServiceAttribute : BeforeAfterTestAttribute
{
    private readonly DataServiceHost serviceHost;

    public UseDataServiceAttribute(Type serviceToHost)
    {
        serviceHost = new DataServiceHost(serviceToHost, new Uri[] { new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DataServiceHostAddress"]) });
    }

    public override void Before(System.Reflection.MethodInfo methodUnderTest)
    {
        try { serviceHost.Open(); }
        catch
        {
            try { serviceHost.Close(); }
            catch
            {
                try { serviceHost.Abort(); }
                catch { }
            }
        }
        base.Before(methodUnderTest);
    }

    public override void After(System.Reflection.MethodInfo methodUnderTest)
    {
        base.After(methodUnderTest);
        try { serviceHost.Close(); }
        catch
        {
            try { serviceHost.Abort(); }
            catch { }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the data model class (separate project, referenced by all other projects):

```
public class DatabaseVersionDataModel
{
    private readonly List<DatabaseVersion> templist;
    public DatabaseVersionDataModel()
    {
        templist = new List<DatabaseVersion> { 
            new DatabaseVersion() { 
                MajorVersionId = 0, 
                MinorVersionId = 0, 
                BuildVersionId = 0, 
                VersionId = 1 } 
        };
        DatabaseVersions = templist.AsQueryable();
    }
    public IQueryable<DatabaseVersion> DatabaseVersions { get; private set; }
}
```

Here is the database version class also in model project:

```
[DataServiceKey("VersionId")]
public class DatabaseVersion
{
    public int VersionId { get; set; }
    public int MajorVersionId { get; set; }
    public int MinorVersionId { get; set; }
    public int BuildVersionId { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the DatabaseVersionService.svc file in my data services project (empty asp.net, compiles, debugs out of iisexpress and atom or json is browseable):

```
public class DatabaseVersionService : DataService<DatabaseVersionDataModel>
{
    // This method is called only once to initialize service-wide policies.
    public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config)
    {
        // TODO: set rules to indicate which entity sets and service operations are visible, updatable, etc.
        // Examples:
        // config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("MyEntityset", EntitySetRights.AllRead);
        // config.SetServiceOperationAccessRule("MyServiceOperation", ServiceOperationRights.All);
        config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("*", EntitySetRights.AllRead);
        config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion = DataServiceProtocolVersion.V3;
    }
}
```

Here is the output after removing throwingrecursionbehavior and adding omitonrecursionbehavior:

> Result Message:   System.InvalidCastException : Unable to cast object of type 'Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.OmitSpecimen' to type 'skeletor.Domain.DatabaseVersion'.
>   Result StackTrace:
>   at Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.SpecimenFactory`2.Create(Object request, ISpecimenContext context)
>      at Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.NoSpecimenOutputGuard.Create(Object request, ISpecimenContext context)
>      at Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.Postprocessor`1.Create(Object request, ISpecimenContext context)
>      at Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.CompositeSpecimenBuilder.<>c_*DisplayClass6.b*_1(ISpecimenBuilder b)
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectListIterator`2.MoveNext()
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.d_*a5`1.MoveNext()
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
>      at Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.CompositeSpecimenBuilder.Create(Object request, ISpecimenContext context)
>      at Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.FilteringSpecimenBuilder.Create(Object request, ISpecimenContext context)
>      at Ploeh.AutoFixture.Dsl.NodeComposer`1.Create(Object request, ISpecimenContext context)
>      at Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.CompositeSpecimenBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass6.<Create>b__1(ISpecimenBuilder b)
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectListIterator`2.MoveNext()
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.<DefaultIfEmptyIterator>d__a5`1.MoveNext()
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
>      at Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.CompositeSpecimenBuilder.Create(Object request, ISpecimenContext context)
>      at Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.RecursionGuard.Create(Object request, ISpecimenContext context)
>      at Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.RecursionGuard.Create(Object request, ISpecimenContext context)
>      at Ploeh.AutoFixture.Dsl.CompositeNodeComposer`1.Create(Object request, ISpecimenContext context)
>      at Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.SpecimenContext.Resolve(Object request)
>      at Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.SpecimenFactory`2.Create(Object request, ISpecimenContext context)
>      at Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.NoSpecimenOutputGuard.Create(Object request, ISpecimenContext context)
>      at Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.Postprocessor`1.Create(Object request, ISpecimenContext context)
>      at Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.CompositeSpecimenBuilder.<>c*_DisplayClass6.b_*1(ISpecimenBuilder b)
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectListIterator`2.MoveNext()
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.d*_a5`1.MoveNext()
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
>      at Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.CompositeSpecimenBuilder.Create(Object request, ISpecimenContext context)
>      at Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.FilteringSpecimenBuilder.Create(Object request, ISpecimenContext context)
>      at Ploeh.AutoFixture.Dsl.NodeComposer`1.Create(Object request, ISpecimenContext context)
>      at Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.CompositeSpecimenBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass6.<Create>b__1(ISpecimenBuilder b)
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectListIterator`2.MoveNext()
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.<DefaultIfEmptyIterator>d__a5`1.MoveNext()
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
>      at Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.CompositeSpecimenBuilder.Create(Object request, ISpecimenContext context)
>      at Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.RecursionGuard.Create(Object request, ISpecimenContext context)
>      at Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.RecursionGuard.Create(Object request, ISpecimenContext context)
>      at Ploeh.AutoFixture.Dsl.CompositeNodeComposer`1.Create(Object request, ISpecimenContext context)
>      at Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.SpecimenContext.Resolve(Object request)
>      at Ploeh.AutoFixture.SpecimenFactory.CreateAnonymous[T](ISpecimenContext context, T seed)
>      at Ploeh.AutoFixture.SpecimenFactory.CreateAnonymous[T](ISpecimenContext context)
>      at Ploeh.AutoFixture.SpecimenFactory.CreateAnonymous[T](ISpecimenBuilderComposer composer)
>      at Ploeh.AutoFixture.SpecimenFactory.CreateAnonymous[T](IPostprocessComposer`1 composer)
>      at skeletor.AcceptanceTests.InfrstructureTests.DataServiceGetsDatabaseVersion() in d:\projects\skeletor\skeletor.AcceptanceTests\InfrstructureTests.cs:line 31

Comment: I am trying to compile the code samples. Do you use [WCF Data Services 5.0 for OData V3](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29306)?

Comment: 5.3, fresh of NuGet and there is an installer if that makes any difference.  I will post the code for the actual service in a second.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that you use WCF Data Services 5.* for OData V3, you can try the following:

#### Supplying a custom Uri:

As with any other generated specimen, it is possible to completely take over it's creation. We can customize the creation of any `Uri` as follows:

```
public class CustomUriBuilder : ISpecimenBuilder
{
    public object Create(object request, ISpecimenContext context)
    {
        if (request == typeof(Uri))
        {
            return new Uri(
                ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DataServiceHostAddress"]);
        }

        return new NoSpecimen(request);
    }
}
```

Using the above custom `ISpecimenBuilder` type, each time a `Uri` is requested, a predefined `Uri` will be returned.

#### Customizing the Fixture instance:

The test `DataServiceGetsDatabaseVersion` can now be rewritten:

```
[Fact]
[UseDataService(typeof(DatabaseVersionService))]
public void DataServiceGetsDatabaseVersion()
{
    var fixture = new Fixture();
    fixture.Customize<VersionClientProxy>(c => c.OmitAutoProperties());
    fixture.Customizations.Add(new CustomUriBuilder());
    fixture.Inject(
        new DatabaseVersion
        {
            MajorVersionId = 0,
            MinorVersionId = 0,
            BuildVersionId = 0,
            VersionId = 1
        });

    var sut = fixture.CreateAnonymous<VersionClientProxy>();
    var version = fixture.CreateAnonymous<DatabaseVersion>();
    var expected = version.AsSource().OfLikeness<DatabaseVersion>();

    var actual = (from a in sut.DatabaseVersions
                    orderby a.VersionId descending
                    select a).FirstOrDefault();

    Assert.True(expected.Equals(actual));
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: This works, but I need to understand a bit better if you don't mind.  1) I'm unsure the difference between Build and Customize... what is the big difference between the two? 2) Why the use of Inject instead of build for creating the expected, what is the big difference?

Comment: In the test we customized the creation algorithm for all Uris using the `Customize` method. The `Build` method would not really help as it ignores any previous Customizations. On the other hand, when requesting a `DatabaseVersion` we customized the creation algorithm to return a specific instance so we used the `Inject` method.